# What modules/tools are available for drawing a graph from text/csv file in Perl or PHP?

Tags: php, perl

I have to draw a graph in Perl or PHP. Can you show me any sample code to read from the text or CSV file and plot a graph or chart of pie?

Data would be like this sample in a CSV or text file:

```
01/01/2010  0 
01/02/2010  1
01/03/2010  2
01/04/2010  3
```

Another set of data in text file for chart

```
Column A 20
Column B 10
Column C 02
```

I want to display the value for each column in my pie chart.

Answer (score 2):

There is a perl charting module GD::Graph you can take a look at.
http://search.cpan.org/dist/GDGraph/Graph.pm

It is pretty old and has limitations, but it can produce simple charts.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [google's charts api](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) to generate an image from the data.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using PHPExcel for over a year now; I think it's one of the best PHP Excel tools out there (it does CSVs too).  You can import the CSV file, generate a graph, and export it in just a few lines of code.

http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/